# Reading cmd format (model.json) to create External Tables in Azure Synapse Serverlees Pool from ADLS containing CRM tables. How can it be resolved?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, cdma

My ADLS Gen2 receives tables from CRM's Dataverse in CDM format (with model.json) using Azure Synapse Link which is cofigured to link just to Storage Account (without Synapse Anlytics).
Now I want to create External Tables in my Synapse Analytics Serverless SQL Pool out of the CRM tables in the Storage Account.

The CSV files of the tables are without column names, the metadata of the tables are in model.json.

How can I tell Synapse to use that model.json for creation of the External Tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can read CDM format and create SQL script. Execute sql script on serverless sql.

You can refer full solution implementation here:
https://github.com/microsoft/Dynamics-365-FastTrack-Implementation-Assets/blob/master/Analytics/CDMUtilSolution/readme.md

Another approach is to implement similar logic in Synapse notebook and execute pipeline on trigger.